# Daily vs Monthly vs. other return for volatility calculation?

Tags: volatility, returns, variance, covariance, standard-deviation

I thought I read/heard somewhere that annualized volatility, using monthly returns vs daily returns is usually lower.  With that said, I can't seem to find any papers on this.

Does anyone have any studies that looks at annualized volatility using different return calculation time frames?

I'm tempted to use daily returns because it increases the number of observations, which I would like, but if it increases volatility, I'd prefer to keep volatility lower.

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise? Just computing something for the sake of it ,or - even worse -  with a "result" in mind (low vol)  is usually not particularly useful.

Comment: I would like to calculate volatilies, but use the smaller one in my model.  I can't perform the exercise myself since I have data contraints, don't want to be pulling data for 500 tickers and see on average if daily or monthly annualized vol is higher/lower

Comment: You still need to further elaborate on what your end goal is. What model are we talking about? Is this portfolio modelling, risk management or something entirely different? IMO, selecting a sampling frequency that fits your narrative can lead to selection bias.

Comment: The question is which return calc produces lower variance, not which return calc is the best.  The latter is an opinion.  The former can be shown via historical analysis.

Comment: Which method do you use to annualize daily or monthly volatility?

Comment: * sqrt(252) or * sqrt(12)

Comment: @confused It's fine that you want to figure out which calculations produce lower variance (on average), but I thought there was some motivational factor with your study. Eg. using your results with regards to portfolio modelling or risk management.  When we are using the scaling rules, $\sigma_y = \sigma_m \cdot \sqrt{12}$, we are implicitly assuming that the return process is serially uncorrelated and are sampled from the same distribution with common variance. Paul Brennans chapter recommendation details what happens when we relax the assumption of serial uncorrelatedness.

Comment: The results just need to be defendable, the market is efficient anyways and past data can't predict the futre.  Based off what you said, daily returns are probably more serial correlated than monthly returns I believe.   I just need a way to narrow or widen confidence intervals depending on use case without doing anything egregious.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen a paper on this result but there is a good section in a book "Modern Investment Management: An Equilibrium Approach" by Bob Litterman

The chapter is Covariance Matrix Estimation by Giorgio De Santis, Bob Litterman, Adrien Vesval, and Kurt Winkelmann.  This talks about the issues around using daily weekly, monthly and yearly returns to estimate covariance matrices and the risk that can be calculated with them.

It was very informative, but unfortunately the book is not cheep.

Comment: You may be able to access a copy of  book by googling: Bob Litterman elibrary.gci.edu.np